# problem with material-ui Switch and final-form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with Switch component from MUI. 
This is the case:
I get the data from the server whether the person is an administrator or not (true/false).
In a form that is used to edit data about a person (final-form) I assign this data to initialState (so if the server returned "isAdministrator = true" then the Switch should be checked). 
And here is the problem, because if the server returns true, the Switch stops working and i can't change the state, if the server returns false, the Switch works normally.

Code: 
*Form.tsx:*

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} initialValues={{ isAdministrator: data.isAdministrator }}>
  {
    ({...renderProps}) => (
      <form onSubmit={renderProps.onSubmit}>
       <Field
         component={FormSwitch}
         disabled={disabled}
         id="admin-switch"
         name={'isAdministrator'}
         type="checkbox" />
      <form>
    )
  }
 </Form>
```

*FormSwitch.tsx*

```
interface IFormInputProps extends FieldRenderProps<any> {
  additionalClassName?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  id?: string;
  label?: string;
}

const FormSwitch: FC<IFormInputProps> = ({
  disabled,
  id,
  input,
  label,
  ...props
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (input.value === null || input.value === undefined) {
      input.onChange(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Switch
      classesSwitch={{
        root: 'switch-root',
        thumb: 'switch-thumb',
        checked: 'switch-checked',
        switchBase: 'switch-base',
      }}
      classesWrapper={{ root: 'switchWrapper' }}
      disabled={disabled}
      label={"test label"}
      {...props}
      {...input}
    />
  );
};
```

*Switch.tsx*

```
import {
  default as ReactSwitch,
  SwitchClassKey,
  SwitchProps,
} from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import FormControlLabel, {
  FormControlLabelClassKey,
} from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import './Switch.scss';
import { FC } from 'react';

interface ISwitchProps extends SwitchProps {
  classesSwitch?: Record<SwitchClassKey | any, string>;
  classesWrapper?: Record<FormControlLabelClassKey | any, string>;
  disabled?: boolean;
  label?: string;
}

export const Switch: FC<ISwitchProps> = (props) => (
  <FormControlLabel
    classes={{ ...props.classesWrapper }}
    control={
      <ReactSwitch
        checked={props.checked}
        classes={{ disabled: 'switch-disabled', ...props.classesSwitch }}
        disabled={props.disabled}
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
    }
    label={props.label}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `defaultChecked={props.checked}` instead of `checked={props.checked}`.